# some money to use for poor people

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, syntax

> I have some money in my bank account to use for poor people.

That's my sentence. The part at the end (**to use for poor people**) is intended to refer back to "**some money**".

The intended meaning is:

> I have some money in my bank account and we can use it [that money] for poor people.

Is this sentence OK grammatically?

Comment: ...for poor people= for the poor

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically correct. But so is the "intended meaning" version, and it might be better.

Saying "for poor people" is rather odd. "For charity" might be better. Who are you talking to here? If you're talking about your plans with a friend:

> I have some money in my bank account which I can donate to charity.
>
> I have some money in my bank account to donate to charity

(or "I plan to donate" or even "I'm going to donate")

Comment: Well, what about "I have some money in my bank account to donate to charity?

Comment: Fine, but what is the wider context?

Comment: It may be culturally correct to say poor people in the OP's country....

Comment: @James K  I don't disagree with your response, however, depending on the reason that  the OP is putting this in writing, it may need to be amended. Not all charities advocate on behalf of, or provide assistance to, people who are poor. There are charities that raise money for education, environmentalism, sport, culture, science, medicine, etc. If the OP wants his/her funds restricted to a particular form of charity, he/she may need to specify this in writing.